# Can I purge configuration files after I've removed the package?

Tags: package-management

I was doing a package removal with `apt-get remove` but then realized I should have done a `--purge` along with it to remove the configuration files.

Can I remove the packages configuration files easily or do I need to reinstall the package and then remove with a `--purge`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes you can.

From the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge packagename
```

This will remove all of the remaining files that the package installed.

---

You can also do this from a GUI:

- Install [Synaptic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/synaptic) [image: Install Synaptic] from the Software Center
- Run Synaptic
- Find packages listed under "Not Installed (residual config)"
  [image: Packages with residual configs]
- Right click the package and click, mark for complete removal
  [image: Menu]
- Click the check button on the tool bar and click apply when the dialogue pops up.
  [image: Dialogue]

Comment: Under `apt 1.0.9.2ubuntu2` `apt-get remove --purge` hasn't removed configuration files or databases if issued after the package was removed, indicating that `Package xxxx is not installed, so not removed`. `dpkg --purge` was needed for correct cleanup.

Comment: My old php config files were not purged using this method.

Comment: @Loenix any files you've added to the folder or, any files within `~/.config` will NOT be removed.

Comment: Similarly, in more recent Apt 2.6.1: `sudo apt purge <pkg>` did purge the residual config of a previously removed package.

Answer (score 70):

Here is a simple command that will meet your request:

```
dpkg --purge $(dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1)
```

Comment: @user1133275 I am very confused, are you complaining about the backticks?

Comment: You should explain what exactly that command does. Somehow it removed mysql from a server I ran it on.

Answer (score 13):

You can purge all previously uninstalled packages with `aptitude`:

```
aptitude purge ?config-files
```

You can also purge individual packages but then you would also have to purge the dependencies one by one. It is not practical.

Comment: My old php config files were not purged using this method.

Answer (score 3):

Or on newer systems:

```
apt purge ?config-files
```

Answer (score 1):

Purge do not remove configuration file atleast in my case it was not able to remove configuration file.

To remove configuration file:

1. Get list of all configuration directory.

```
    cd ~/.config
    ls
```

2. Remove the directories containing configuration for packagename

```
    rm -rf packagename
```

Comment: Finally, this was the only solution working to remove my old php configuration files...