# Black screen after entering the password on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, ubuntu-gnome

I'm having this issue where I enter my password and all I get is a black screen with the mouse cursor moving around, it's the [same closed issue from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768299/black-screen-after-login-ubuntu-gnome-16-04).

Purging package configuration doesn't do anything, and lately pressing CTR + ALT + F1 won't bring up the console like it should, so I have to shutdown the system and start again!

My kernel version is: 4.4.0.53 and I have an Intel graphics card.

Could it be related to the /dev/sda1: recovering journal? I've been getting that more often lately (we have electrical issues).

At times the boot logo would delay for several minutes as well, is that related?

Found this link on launch pad that is similar to my issue: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1559576

Comment: Problem is still occurring, I need help please! I can't even run the command shell with `CTRL + ALT + F1`

Comment: Happened twice this morning..

Comment: Could you boot the defected kernel without login switch to console and get output of `uname -a` & `sudo lshw -c display`  . Is this issue still with last kernel update? What is the version of the last working kernel?

Comment: Could you give me more specific details?

Comment: Sure, I'm expecting a graphic driver issue, so could you run these tests: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23658579/

Comment: Please note that with Ubuntu GNOME 16.10, gdm runs on virtual terminal 1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and the first logged in user runs on virtual terminal 2 (Ctrl+Alt+F2). Use Ctrl+Alt+F3 (or higher) if you want an available virtual terminal to use.

Comment: I preformed the first test and it booted normally, then went back to the latest kernel and checked it, then preformed the tests @user.dz

Comment: *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)

Comment: `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic root=UUID=abadd503-d536-48b3-97b0-d41003828c77 ro recovery nomodeset`

Comment: @JeremyBicha Didn't work sadly, but thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in this [launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1559576) there is a bug affecting Lenovo laptops that has Ubuntu Gnome installed, and it's not resolved yet. The only workaround is to install LightDM and set it as the default login manager.

Comment: Do 3D applications work fine now, like `glxgears`?

Comment: I'll have to try that app to tell you, I already attached the tests for you @user.dz

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error in the last kernel update.
Try to use an older kernel version under extended boot options.

```
4.4.0.42 --> stable ! with Intel GPU.
```

Comment: It's been happening since earlier kernels.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know surely, but had this problem once too when I was frickling with nvidia-driver in the past with Ubuntu 13.10.
You might try following three steps in terminal :

1.)

> sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop

2.)

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

3.)

> sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start

Instead of step 2.) you might try :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg

Hope this hits as solution to you.
In case gdm was lost before you might try too :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm

In the end you should clean up with :

> sudo apt-get autoremove

In case gdm was not installed with gnome together, then after:

> sudo apt-get install gdm

there should following :

> sudo service lightdm stop

and

> sudo service gdm start

Then reboot the machine.

Comment: I tried your solution, commands 1 and 3 weren't recognized so I just reinstalled xserver-xorg and gdm. Several restarts later the problem still occurs! @dschinn1011

Comment: @Muaad ElSharif - have re-edited my answer with additions. As I see gdm was not installed in the  beginning of gnome. So you need to switch from lightdm to gdm.

Comment: I did the exact opposite! I'm working fine with Lightdm now!

Comment: @Muaad ElSharif - you should Check if gdm works as described in answer. Before you after reboot log in with password there is in lightdm in menu of login window Option to select gnome - otherwise if gnome is not working, then you should report this as bug in gnome.

Comment: The bug exists and it's on launchpad, you can find it in my answer below.