# Deleting standard browser

Tags: apt, firefox, uninstall

Is there any difference between this command:
`apt-get purge firefox`

and these 2 commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: `apt-get autoremove --purge firefox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get remove firefox` just uninstalls Firefox.

`sudo apt-get purge firefox` also deletes configuration files.

`sudo apt-get autoremove` removes packages that were automatically
installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no
longer needed.

Comment: So, does not autoremove delete config files? Ok, if does not, how can i delete configs if i deleted app using remove command, not purge? How can i know where are configs? If u cant read my english, sorry, please(

Comment: If you already used `remove` but want to `purge`, follow [these instructions.](http://askubuntu.com/a/104131/451919). BTW, I probably don't know much more about all this than you do, I just searched my way to these answers.